# Error al consumir POST de servicio restful java en cliente PHP

Tags: php, restful

Tengo un servicio RestFul hecho en java del cual he podido obtener la lista de productos que tengo registrados en la BD, pero al momento de llamar a la función POST para insertar uno me lanza un error: "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.", le envío un array Json y el codigo que uso en el cliente PHP es el siguiente:

```
$proJson=array(
                    "codigoProducto"=>0, 
                    "descripcion"=>$Descripcion, 
                    "descuento"=>$Descuento, 
                    "precio"=>$Precio, 
                    "existenciaMinima"=>$ExistenciaMinima, 
                    "existenciaMaxima"=>$ExistenciaMaxima, 
                    "existencia"=>$Existencia, 
                    "fechaVencimiento"=>$FechaVencimiento, 
                    "activo"=>true, 
                    "codigoCategoria"=>$CodigoCategoria, 
                    "codigoMarca"=>$CodigoMarca, 
                    "codigoProveedor"=>$CodigoProveedor, 
                    "codigoUbicacion"=>$CodigoUbicacion
                );

        $data_string = json_encode($proJson);
        //$data_string=xmlrpc_encode($proJson);
        echo($data_string);
        $ch = curl_init('http://localhost:8080/RestFullParcial2/webresources/com.entidades.tblproducto');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
        );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);

        //execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        //close connection
        curl_close($ch);

        echo $result;
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias

Comment: ¿Has intentado usar [guzzle](http://guzzle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/request-options.html) como cliente para hacer las peticiones?, resulta más eficiente y tienes mejor control sobre lo que envías.